# How to get the full console log of my tmux session on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, tmux, console

I have a Linux VM on Google Cloud and it has a tmux session which is running a .py file and I am trying to get the console log, but I can't scroll up or anything.

Any idea?

[image: Here's my console]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't mention how you are trying to scroll.  If you are trying to scroll the terminal window itself, then that won't work since Tmux is a fullscreen app.  It would be like trying to scroll `vim` (or any other editor).

There are multiple options, however:

###### Tmux Copy Mode

The default keybinding for activating the scrollback mechanism for Tmux (known as Copy Mode) is <kbd>Prefix</kbd>(typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), followed by <kbd>[</kbd>.  Then scroll via the arrow keys.

###### Save the entire buffer

You can also retrieve the entire buffer into a file in one of (at least) two ways.  First, if you had a prompt, you could:

```
tmux capture-pane -pS - > ~/tmux-buffer.txt
```

But since you mentioned your Python programming is running, you would need to:

- Access the Tmux command prompt with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>
- Save the pane to a buffer with:

  ```
  capture-pane -S -
  ```
- Access the Tmux prompt again (<kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>)
- Save the buffer to a file with:

  ```
  save-buffer ~/tmux-buffer.txt
  ```

An alternative is to combine the two previous options and run the `tmux` command in a `run-shell`:

- Access the Tmux command prompt with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>
- Run the first Tmux command via:

  ```
  run-shell "tmux capture-pane -pS - > ~/tmux-buffer.txt"
  ```

###### Send buffer to another pager

From the command-line:

```
tmux capture-pane -pS - | less
```

From the Tmux command prompt:

```
run-shell "tmux capture-pane -pS - | less"
```

Even better, keep the escape codes and you can include additional formatting and colors:

```
tmux capture-pane -epS - | less -r
```

###### tee

Finally, don't forget the usefulness of `tee` in this type of situation.  If you know in advance that you will want to capture the output of the program, send it to both the screen and a file using `tee`:

```
python myprog.py 2>&1 | tee ~/myprog-out.txt
```

This will capture both `stdout` and `stderr`, of course.

Of course, with all of the previous Tmux ways of handling it, the extra planning-in-advance really isn't necessary.